# Как получить информацию о покупатели в opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Пишу модуль для opencart 3, но не могу найти как получить информацию о покупатели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абсолютно все методы, что есть в opencart (не имеет значение какой версии) можно найти в папке: `system/library`.
Конкретно для покупателя: `system/library/customer.php`

Методы для получения нужной информации:

```
$this->customer->getFirstName(); // имя
$this->customer->getLastName(); // фамилия
$this->customer->getEmail(); // email
$this->customer->getTelephone(); // телефон
```

и так далее (полный список увидите в файле).

Comment: Хм... я пробовал и почему-то не работало, сейчас ещё раз попробую

Comment: @МикейлоКох должно работать, какая у вас версия opencart?

Comment: @AlexadnerSemikashev всё верно, спасибо. Это я затупил